# WLMail displays messages correctly on screen, but prints Â where there is =C2=A0 for some messages

Tags: email, encoding, character-encoding, windows-live-mail

There are many questions online related to this. And I understand that `=C2=A0` stands for non-breaking space when it appears within a mime part with type: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

My user uses Windows Live Mail Version 2012 (Build 16.4.3508.0205) on Win 7.
The problematic emails tend to have "MsoNormal" as a tell tale sign in message source.

- When the problematic mail is viewed on screen thru WLMail, no problems.
- When the problematic mail is **printed** on paper or to PDF, via WLMail, the Â **do** appear.
- When the problematic mail is viewed in browser or printed via Gmail web interface, no problems.

"Use default encoding for all incoming messages" is NOT checked.

The problematic and good messages both have `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

The only difference I can see is that "MsoNormal" (tell-tale signs that an MS MUA was used by the other party) are present in the problematic messages.

Another clue is that the problematic messages tend to be those that have been authored in MS Outlook/WLMail, and then replied-to by a Gmail-web user, and then received by the WLMail user.